# How to pass non field specific form error message to twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

In top of my twig login form I have

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

after authentication fail, I want to pass a wrong password message here. In my controller I have:

```
echo $twig->render('login.html', 
['form' => $form->createView(),
 'title' => 'title',
 'form.errors' => array('wrong pass');
]);
```

But I assume form.errors is a wrong param to pass non-field-specific errors to twig form. How can I do this? I probably have to add my symfony form is standalone, NOT framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should add errors to the `Form` instance in the PHP code:

```php
// ...
$form->addError(new FormError('wrong pass'));

return new Response($twig->render('login.html', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'title' => 'title',
    'form.errors' => array('wrong pass');
]));
```

---

*I'm btw not so sure whether you would want to have this as a form error*